# Meaning of “we’ll cut him down as for the border he rides”

Tags: sentence-meaning, conjunctions, poetry

Welsh History 101B:

> My neighbour from England has come across raiding, 
>   Slain six of my kinsmen and burned down my hall. 
>   It cannot be borne, this offence and injustice: 
>   I’ve only killed four of his, last I recall. 
>   I’ll send for my neighbours, Llewellyn and Owain; 
>   We’ll cut him down as for the border he rides. 
>   But yesterday Owain stole three of my cattle, 
>   So first I’ll retake them, and three more besides.

I didn’t get the meaning of “we’ll cut him down as for the border he rides”. Please can anybody explain?

Comment: "since he's riding towards the border".

Comment: @RonJohn: "As" isn't "since" here - rather "while" or "at the same time as".

Comment: @psmears since we know he's riding for the border, we know what route he's taking, and thus we can cut him down.

Comment: @psmears: I'd argue that either interpretation is valid (out of context, at least)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right - out of context, either would be fine; context here strongly suggests (to me, at least) that the "at the same time as" meaning is much more likely :)

Comment: @psmears: I think you're probably right.

Comment: He's an Englishman who's been raiding in Wales. They're not going to cut him down because he's fleeing for England, they're going to cut him down for killing 6 kinsman and burning the hall!

Comment: I concur with the existing answers, but I've gotta say that as a native English speaker I couldn't immediately parse the sentence, although maybe it hurt that I saw the relevant phrase out of context (in the question title) first.  I kept trying to read "as" as "because."

Answer (score 36):

> We’ll cut him down as for the border he rides.

Ah, one of the things one *can* do in English, but which is non-idiomatic and thus generally only appears in poetry, is re-arrange clause order like this, sticking the prepositional phrase in the middle of things.

"As" here means "while", and the more conventional place for "for the border" would be at the end:

> We'll cut him down [while] he rides for the border.

"Cut him down" is idiomatic, and means more literally "murder him with swords", though also is used to refer, poetically, to murdering people with other weapons like firearms.

Comment: Actually, the phrase "cut him down" as an alternative to "shoot him" is hardly poetic.

Comment: This is probably from before firearms, so the weapon really would be swords or the like.

Comment: I think you're correct that "as" means "while" in this context. But it might be worth mentioning that in this same type of construction, "as" could mean "because"..

Comment: It may or may not be worth noting that this suggests that they will kill him while he is in their lands and somewhat vulnerable. If he reaches the border, he is in his lands with stronger defenses.

Comment: Or it it could mean they wish to kill him for fleeing/desertion

Comment: It may be worth noting that the idiom of “cutting” used for killing of all kinds (and of “falling” for dying regardless of cause of death) goes back at least to Latin, where *cidere* (to cut, especially a tree for lumber) and *cadere* (to fall) were idiomatic for “to kill” and “to die” respectively (and *cidere* is the source of the *-cide* suffix in English, as used in *homicide* from *homo* for man, *suicide* from *sui* for himself, *patricide* from *pater* for father, *regicide* from *rex* for king, and so on).

Answer (score 12):

> We’ll cut him down as for the border he rides.

means "We will kill him **while** he rides towards the border".

Comment: Or more faithfully to the original, "We'll kill him as he rides for [to] the border"